# IIS 7.5 physical path with no extension

Tags: php, iis

I cannot figure out why my PHP installation is requesting a physical path without an extension.

Requested URL   http://localhost:80/index

Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index

[image: Error message]

PHP is working fine with phpinfo.

web.config contents (although the error is unchanged regardless of whether the web.config file exists in the root folder or not): https://pastebin.com/5E2x3yeP

I have tried Googling and to my surprise no results related to a physical path showing no extension. I'm sure I'm missing something silly in the php.ini or something. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Who wrote the rules in `web.config`? None of them would redirect http://localhost:80:index to http://localhost:80/index.php, and that's exactly why IIS checks and responds 404.

Comment: The issue was unrelated to the web.config file and was fixed by re-installing IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you request an URL, a web server does the following:

- sees if a file name matching the URL exists. If yes, it will sent it to the client.
- otherwise, checks if a directory with this name exists. If it does, the  following will happen:

  - If there is a file in that directory that the server considers as an index file, it will show this (that's the usual `index.html` case).
  - It this doesn't exist but the server is configured to show the contents of the directory, it will list all file names.
  - If neither is the case, an error will be shown.
- If neither a filename nor a directory exists with the same name, there also will be an error (404).

So, in your case, everything works as expected, as you just requested the name `index`, which apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: I appreciate that information. The CMS is coded to automatically redirect index.php to index. I have edited the original question with the web.config contents. Although the issue still occurs regardless of whether the web.config file exists or not. I think the issue lies in the PHP or IIS configuration where it is not retrieving the correct physical file, as it shows no extension for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Internet Information Services (IIS)
2. Click on "PHP Manager"
3. Click on "Register new PHP version"
4. Locate the php(usually,C:/Program Files(86)/php-version)
5. Choose php.exe or php-cgi.exe